# Calculate middle date

Tags: javascript, date

I want to calculate the middle between two dates in Javascript. So I tried:

```
var middate = (startdate+enddate)/2;
console.log(middate);
```

which logs

```
NaN
```

What is the problem?

Comment: where is startdate and enddate? Have you declared somewhere? Show us and the rest of the code

Comment: `startdate+enddate` will give you a string

Comment: date objects cannot be handled like this , so if you want middle date calculate difference between two days and then divide it by 2 and the add number of days to startdate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Middle of two dates" is not unambiguously defined - you must decide how to handle dates an odd number of days apart (e.g. what is the middle date between 1st and 4th of a month, or between 1st and 2nd), and what to do with the time portion of the date object.

The concrete problem with your approach is that dates are not numbers, so you cannot add them and divide them by two. To do that, use the `getTime()` method to obtain the number of seconds since the epoch, and operate on that:

```
var middate = new Date((startdate.getTime() + enddate.getTime()) / 2);
```

This will give you the middle between two dates, treating them as points in time.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
date1 = new Date("Feb 10 2014")
date2 = new Date("Feb 12 2014")
middle = new Date(date2 - (date2-date1)/2);
console.log(middle);
```

Comment: it is calculating only two dates what we have to do if date2 is more than 12 feb? please get back to me

Answer (score 0):

using `moment js` you can do this like this.

```
const getMidTimeBetweenTwoDate = (date1, date2) => {
  let date1Moment = moment(date1);
  let date2Moment = moment(date2);
  let diff = date2Moment.diff(date1Moment, 'minutes');
  let midTime = date1Moment.add(diff/2, 'minutes');
  return midTime;
}
```