# Find the Median Date between two dates using Java 8

Tags: java, java-time

I'm finding it difficult that what it sounds.

So, I have a max date and a min date and I need to find the median date between these two dates. I use Java 8 to find my max and min dates,

```
LocalDate gerbutsmin = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(2).atDay(1);
LocalDate gerbutsmax = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(15).atDay(1);
```

How would I go ahead after this? Maybe I need to switch back to Calander?

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry, messed that up. it is java.time

Comment: Hi @Sriram, I believe Tim's answer is better than mine and it should be accepted instead of mine.

Comment: @nytez Nah...your code runs, I tested it.  Enjoy the onslaught of green points in your inbox :P

Comment: There should be no reason to switch back to `Calendar` (and many reasons not to). Median? Do you mean average? The median between two points doesn’t seem very interesting, and I know of a couple of different definitions of what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LocalDate gerbutsmin = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(2).atDay(1);
LocalDate gerbutsmax = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(15).atDay(1);

LocalDate median = gerbutsmin.plusDays(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(gerbutsmin, gerbutsmax) / 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using `DAYS.between()`:

```
LocalDate gerbutsmin = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(2).atDay(1);
LocalDate gerbutsmax = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(15).atDay(1);
long numDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(gerbutsmin, gerbutsmax);
LocalDate median = gerbutsmin.plusDays(numDays / 2L);  // plusDays takes a long
System.out.println(median);

2019-03-17
(output as of today, which is 2019-07-26)
```

### Demo

There is a boundary condition should the difference between your min and max dates be an odd number.  In this case, there is no formal median day, but rather the median would fall in between two days.

**Note:**

If you're wondering what happens exactly in the edge case, if the low date were today (`2018-07-26`) and the high date three days away (`2018-07-29`), then the median would be reported as `2018-07-27`.

Answer (score 0):

"Middle of two dates" is not unambiguously defined - you must decide how to handle dates an odd number of days apart (e.g. what is the middle date between 1st and 4th of a month, or between 1st and 2nd), and what to do with the time portion of the date object.

The concrete problem with your approach is that dates are not numbers, so you cannot add them and divide them by two. To do that, use the getTime() method to obtain the number of seconds since the epoch, and operate on that:

```
var middate = new Date((startdate.getTime() + enddate.getTime()) / 2.0);
```

This will give you the middle between two dates, treating them as points in time.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603229/9130223)

Comment: Point about ambiguity taken. When Java 8 is asked about and the asker explicitly uses `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, please don’t suggest using the long outdated and poorly designed `Date` class instead. java.time has all the functionality needed and more.

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime startime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime endtime = startime.plusDays(4);
    
long diff = endtime.until(startime, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
LocalDateTime middleTime = startime.plusMinutes(diff / 2);
```